# Simple SpringMVC 3 Login doesn't work

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make work a simple login webpage in Spring MVC 3.0 through annotations. After dealing with it for several hours I haven't been able to run it. I believe the problem is with the dispatcher, but I've tried a lot of things but with no success... I'll post some code:

LoginView.jsp (only form shown)

```
<form:form method="post" action="doLogin" commandName="login" modelAttribute="login">
        <p> <form:input path="username"/> </p>
        <p> <form:input path="password"/> </p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
</form:form>
```

Login.java is quite easy, as it only contains username and pasword attributes and their setters/getters.

LoginController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("doLogin")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(Map model) {
        Login login = new Login();
        model.put("login", login);
        return "LoginView";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(Login login, BindingResult result, Map model) {
        String userName = "Admin";
        String password = "root";
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "login";
        }
        login = (Login) model.get("login");
        if (!login.getUsername().equals(userName) || !login.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            return "loginerror";
        }
        model.put("login", login);
        return "loginsuccess";
    }
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="spring.blog.src"/>  

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="LoginView.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="indexController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
        <property name="viewName">
            <value>LoginView</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I know there something wrong here, but don't know exactly what....
The error thrown by Tomcat is (I'm sorry, some lines are in spanish...)

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP /WEB-INF/jsp/LoginView.jsp en línea 26

24:       <form:form method="post" action="doLogin" commandName="login">
25:         <!-- <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p> -->
26:         <p> <form:input path="username"/> </p>
27:         <!-- <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p> -->
28:         <p> <form:input path="password"/> </p>
29:         <p class="remember_me">

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:521)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:424)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)

causa raíz

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
```

I'll apreciate any help !!

Comment: Are you getting the error after you call the post?  I am guessing you can pull up the login form ok but just can't get the view to show up after you post.

Comment: Why do you have this line: login = (Login) model.get("login");... The Login object passed to the method should be populated with all of the form information.

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature should look like what is below.  The signature needed the @ModelAttribute annotation.  The model is not needed as part of the signature.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute Login login, BindingResult result) {
    String userName = "Admin";
    String password = "root";
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "login";
    }
    if (!login.getUsername().equals(userName) || !login.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        return "loginerror";
    }
    return "loginsuccess";
}
```

Also your jsp will just need the command name attribute and not the modelAttribute on the form:form tag.

```
<form:form method="post" action="doLogin" commandName="login">
```

Comment: Exactly, but without the model.get("login")

Comment: @PatBurke thanks.  I thought I had taken that out.  I will remove it from the answer.

Comment: I changed what you suggested, but keeps retrieving the same error "Neither BindingResult nor plain......"

Comment: Is the error coming from the jsp?  It would help if you add a few more lines of the stack to your post.

Comment: @Hauri are you going through the controller method to display the view?  so some url like http://localhost:8080/mycontext/doLogin

Comment: Well...in fact the main page should be `localhost:8080/mycontext/LoginView.jsp`, as you can see in the code I posted from my dispatcher, but it doesn't even load it properly (it just retrieves that error I told you...). Thanks!!

Comment: @Hauri Unfortunately you cannot go directly to the jsp because if not the model attribute is not set and hence why you are getting the exceptions on the form:form tag.  That is why you must go through the doLogin path which will hit the controller method, add the model attribute and set the view to LoginView.jsp as your showForm method states.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get the idea... I'm just trying to load as first page LoginView.jsp, and that is what my dispatcher is supposed to be doing. However, you say the path is not correct and should be "doLogin". Could you explain me this with more detail? Thank you very much!!